# Category theory and arithmetic

Tags: category-theory

My question is concerned by “proofs of” or “guesses” of arithmetical identities using category theory.  I’m not at all a specialist of CT but I try to put my hands on and to understand something in this fascinating subject. Using the concepts of product and coproduct in a specific category, gives me the “right” path to prove an arithmetic identity. When I look to purely arithmetical proofs of this identity, they use quite strong results like decomposition in prime numbers or Bezout identity etc..

In some sens, CT allows to prove it with minimalistic assumption, only the notion of divisibility  between integers without referring to prime numbers or other specific identities like Bezout.

I do not want necessarily to go through that specific proof but I was asking myself (and googling around gave me no results…)  if there are example of arithmetical identities being proved or which have been simplified (in the above sense) by a categorical approach and also maybe if some new arithmetical identities have been guessed through CT.

Thanks for any comment or pointer

Comment: You may be interested in Fiore–Leinster's [Objects of Categories as Complex Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377), which discusses when arithmetic identities may be proved in arbitrary rig categories.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!